# OCaml's `type a. a t` syntax

Tags: syntax, ocaml, gadt, locally-abstract-type

I've just come across the following code snippet in [OCaml's documentation about GADTs](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc85):

```
let rec eval : type a. a term -> a = function
  | Int n -> n
  | Add -> (fun x y -> x + y)
  | App (f, x) -> (eval f) (eval x)
```

which, once evaluated in utop, has the following signature:

```
val eval : 'a term -> 'a = <fun>
```

I also noticed that, when replacing `type a. a term -> a` by `'a term -> 'a` or just removing the signature, the function doesn't compile anymore.

```
...
| Add -> (fun x y -> x + y)
...
Error: This pattern matches values of type (int -> int -> int) term
  but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int term
  Type int -> int -> int is not compatible with type int
```

So what is this notation? What makes it different of `'a t` ?

Is it specific to GADTs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual explains the syntax a few sections up: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc80

In short, `type a. ...` means that the locally abstract type `a` must be polymorphic.

Comment: no, it isn't polymorphic. That is what `'a . ` is for (see 7.12 in the manual). The type system will not consider `let f (x:'a) : 'a = x + 1` an error, since `int` can unify. What the `type a` does, is create a locally abstract type. In GADTs, each branch could have a different type instantiated as `a` as the example `Antoine` shows. In situations where you want to use a concrete type in a polymorphic function this allows the type to be referenced.

Comment: @nlucaroni `type a. ...` does enforce that `a` be polymorphic. It is a combination of `'a. ...` (which enforces polymorphism) and `(type a)` (which declares a locally abstract type).

Comment: updated link: https://ocaml.org/manual/locallyabstract.html explaining (type a) as well as how `type a.` desugars.

And `'a` syntax is documented in https://ocamlverse.github.io/content/weak_type_variables.html